# Can we define height and width of an element using em units in css?

Tags: css

I have seen many times as highly skilled web designers/developers apply em unit in font-size as well as for margin and padding, I am curious to know that em unit could also be applied on the height and width of the element? OR we can stick with pixels on that.

Comment: Just trying it would answer your question really quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, you can use `em` (and `pt`, `%` and [all the others](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#lengths)) for `width` and `height`, too.